# Google Chrome Extension Collapsible Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to create a collapsible menu within my google chrome extension. My extension is simply an icon on the right of the address bar which has a popup bar when clicked on. I used the syntax given on this site: http://tommcfarlin.com/collapsible-menus/ but when i run my extension it just shows the list as bulletin points without any table or collapsing effect. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Providing us with your code as well as the example would be really helpful. Otherwise we do not know what you could have possibly made and error on. Please edit your question and include some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed Step 2:
You may have added the `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.collapsible-menus.min.js"></script>` in you html but you didn't download the `jquery.collapsible-menus.min.js` file. If you have downloaded it and added it to your working directory, and followed the steps then there must be no errors.

For example:

Directory structure:

`myextention`
`-js`
  `-jquery.collapsible-menus.min.js`
`-css`
`-img`
`-index.html`

You should change this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.collapsible-menus.min.js"></script>`
to
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.collapsible-menus.min.js"></script>`

Hope it helps.